# How to update state with react js with componentDidUpdate and setState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to update the data with react js eg a user writes a comment how to make this messages show up to all other users?
I used setState in componentDidUpdate with a stop condition but it doesn't work.
If i don't make a condition, it work correctely but with infinite loop.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) { 
console.log("1" + prevState.changeRepComm.toString())
console.log("2" + this.state.changeRepComm.toString())
 if (prevState.changeRepComm !== this.state.changeRepComm ) {
  if (this.updateTimer) return;     
      this.updateTimer = setTimeout(() => {
      //lister response comments
     fetch('/api/ReponseCommentaire/listerReponseCommentaire', {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json, application/xml, text/plain, text/html, *.*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => {
        console.log('Ajouter response:' + JSON.stringify(response))
        this.setState({ ...this.state, reponseCommentaires: response });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log('fetch failed => ', err);
      })

  }, 1000);
```

}  }

Comment: What's the root cause? Is it an issue with your condition? Is fetch/setState not being ran at all? If so, which condition is the issue?

Comment: the problem's that this.state.changeRepComm changed quickly when the user write a comment and the other user can't see the change. this.state.changeRepComm  is boolean value changed to true when the user write a comment.

Comment: Is the update timer suppose to run every 1000ms or does it only need to run once? If it keeps running you should be using setInterval instead of setTimeout

Comment: i want to use setIntervalle instead of setTimeOut and see if it works fine. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If your looking to update every second, you can initialize a timer when component mounts.

```
componentDidMount(prevProps, prevState) { 
    if (this.updateTimer) { return; }  

    this.updateTimer = setInterval(() => {
      fetch('/api/ReponseCommentaire/listerReponseCommentaire', {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json, application/xml, text/plain, text/html, *.*',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          ...this.state,
          reponseCommentaires: response,
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log('fetch failed => ', err) )

    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: i'm going to try it.thank you